# Eventlet threads do not run in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, proxy, eventlet

I wrote the following code:

```
import eventlet
import requests
import redis

redis = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port="6379", db=0)

proxy_1_pool = eventlet.GreenPool(40)

def fetch_items():
    for _ in range(0, 400):
        proxy_1_pool.spawn(fetch_listing)

    proxy_1_pool.waitall()

def fetch_listing():
    logger.info("START fetch: " + str(datetime.utcnow()))
    url_info = redis.spop("listings_to_crawl")
    content = make_request(url_info)
    logger.info("END fetch: " + str(datetime.utcnow()))
    if content:
        do_something(content)

def make_request(url_info):
    r = requests.get(url_info)
    return r.content

def main():
    fetch_items()
```

Unfortunately I see that fetch_listing is being involved sequentially.

It would always print:

```
START
END
START 
END
```

While I would expect to see:

```
START
START
END 
END
```

Comment: (general) construct minimal code to reproduce problem and post every line of that code. (here) do not hide imports and/or monkey patching line.

Comment: Thanks @temoto I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on:

- you asked eventlet to execute multiple `fetch_listing()` concurrently. Parallel as in question title is not going to happen ever, forget about it. And it did as ordered, you can verify by putting `eventlet.sleep()` right after `logger.info...START`
- then execution was blocked by `redis.spop` and `requests.get`.

What you do to make blocking code cooperate with eventlet: [patching](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html) or offload to threadpool.

```
-import eventlet
+import eventlet ; eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

*Very related* questions, highly recommend to read:

- [Celery + Eventlet + non blocking requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315657/celery-eventlet-non-blocking-requests)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14227272/73957

Comment: Thanks. just wondering regarding eventlet.GreenPool(40) -  does that mean that max 40 requests will occur at the same time? because it seems to me that many more actually happen - as my proxy server is limited to 40

Comment: `GreenPool(40)` should work as you expect. If that's not the case, please gather some data or reproduction script and post issue at https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet